# Using \begin{enumerate}[{(1)}] with enumitem

Tags: enumerate, itemize, enumitem, vertical-spacing

So for  lists I would like to be able to use (1)  (2) etc  however I would also like to be able to make compact lists  something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968557/latex-very-compact-itemize

which requires using the package `enumitem`

but that makes `\begin{enumerate}[{(1)}]` not work

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[demo,       % in real document remove this option 
            export]{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[{(1)}]
    \item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;   
\item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You shouldn't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`. On the other hand, `[{(1)}]` doesn't seem something good for either package.

Comment: @egreg  well how do I compact lists with just enumerate then? that's probably the simplest solution

Comment: You don't: `enumerate` only sets the item labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve everything you want using only `enumitem`. To make a really compact list, `enumitem` provides an option `nosep` which removes all spacing before and after the list as well as between the items. You can set the labels to be like (1), (2), etc. in the `label` option of the `enumerate` environment. Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text before to test for spacing.
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*), nosep]
    \item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;   
    \item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint. 
\end{enumerate}
Some text after to test for spacing.

\end{document}
```

[image]

`enumitem` provides a lot of flexibility on the lengths used; see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) for more details.

Also, if you want all of your `enumerate` environments to look like this one, you could set the options directly in the preamble with

```
\setlist[enumerate]{nosep, label=(\arabic*)}
```

and remove the options of the `enumerate` environment within the document.

Answer (score 1):

Tou can define labels with `enumitem` as with `enumerate` if you load it with option `[shortlabels]`. So here is a compact code for a compact list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[(1), nosep]
    \item Each $T \in \mathcal{T}$ is either an even face or contains exactly 2 faces in its interior;
    \item the interiors of distinct $T \in \mathcal{T}$ are disjoint.
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[47]

\end{document}
```

[image]